# Download image from ImageID and collection using Amazon Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I am building a face recogition app using AWS Rekognition. I also want to show the image to user that matches with my input image. Does AWS also saves the image when we index them? If yes, how can I get that image?

If no I am thinking to do it this way. I can save the image into S3 with same name as ExternalImageId so that when ever a face is detected, I read the external id from Rekognition and fetch that from S3.

If there is a better approach than this, please let me know.

I am using following code to index an image in a collection:

```
import boto3
from PIL import Image
import io
import time

image1 = 'images/haad2.jpg'

client = boto3.client('rekognition')
image = Image.open(image1)

stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream, format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.index_faces(
    Image={
        'Bytes': image_binary
    },
    CollectionId='root_faces_data',
    ExternalImageId=str(time.time()),
    DetectionAttributes=[
        'ALL',
    ]
)

print(response)
```

And the following code to see if a face exists in a collection:

```
import boto3
import io
from PIL import Image

client = boto3.client('rekognition')

image1 = 'images/haad2.jpg'

client = boto3.client('rekognition')
image = Image.open(image1)

stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream, format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.search_faces_by_image(
    CollectionId='root_faces_data',
    Image={
        'Bytes': image_binary
    },
    MaxFaces=10,
    FaceMatchThreshold=90
)

print(response)
```

This is the output of search_faces_by_image:

```
{
  'SearchedFaceBoundingBox': {
    'Width': 0.2646464705467224,
    'Height': 0.39817628264427185,
    'Left': 0.3186868727207184,
    'Top': 0.23252280056476593
  },
  'SearchedFaceConfidence': 99.9957275390625,
  'FaceMatches': [
    {
      'Similarity': 99.98405456542969,
      'Face': {
        'FaceId': '5bc98595-7d30-4447-b430-4c0fd8f1b926',
        'BoundingBox': {
          'Width': 0.2646459937095642,
          'Height': 0.39817601442337036,
          'Left': 0.31868699193000793,
          'Top': 0.23252299427986145
        },
        'ImageId': '8e631731-4a0c-513d-be32-dbfe3ae5e813',
        'ExternalImageId': '1534576206.8314612',
        'Confidence': 99.9957046508789
      }
    }
  ],
  'FaceModelVersion': '3.0',
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': 'eca4bea6-a2b5-11e8-9345-a5eddf19f47f',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
      'date': 'Sat, 18 Aug 2018 07:12:09 GMT',
      'x-amzn-requestid': 'eca4bea6-a2b5-11e8-9345-a5eddf19f47f',
      'content-length': '553',
      'connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    'RetryAttempts': 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. When a face is added to a Face Collection, the original image is not kept.

From [Adding Faces to a Collection - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/add-faces-to-collection-procedure.html):

> For each face detected, Amazon Rekognition extracts facial features and stores the feature information in a database. In addition, the command stores metadata for each face that's detected in the specified face collection. **Amazon Rekognition doesn't store the actual image bytes.**

Your idea of storing the original image in Amazon S3 is good. However, you can improve it by using the `BoundingBox` information in the response to `search_faces_by_image()`.

When Amazon Rekognition adds a face to a Face Collection, it searches for the largest face in the input image. The location of this face is provided by `BoundingBox`.

Before storing the original image, you should crop the image using the `BoundingBox` dimensions. Note that these are relative to the dimension size, so you'll need to use something like:

```
(int(face['BoundingBox']['Left'] * width),
 int(face['BoundingBox']['Top'] * height)),
(int((face['BoundingBox']['Left'] + face['BoundingBox']['Width']) * width),
 int((face['BoundingBox']['Top'] + face['BoundingBox']['Height']) * height))
```

The result is that all of your images will be focussed on the faces themselves.

Comment: Wow. That's great. Thanks a lot John.

Comment: Yes. Rekognition mentions that the original images are not kept. I was wondering, what is the significance of ImageId in that case?